# Workbench Moderation: Published data overriding draft data on draft view

Tags: 7, theming, workbench

[Moderation's](https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) draft content not showing on the front end.

When a node has both a published and a draft, the data from the published overrides the draft data on the front end when viewing the draft.

For example www.example.comnode/6
and www.example.com/node/6/draft 
will display identically.

Does this require a special hook in the theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a two-part solution.
There was a bug that needed patch #16 from here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation/issues/2021903

I also needed to add vid to node_load:
    When I combined the 
    `$vids = $node->vid;
    $node = node_load( $nid, $vids );` 
    with patch #16 from: 
    https://www.drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation/issues/2021903 it solves the issue.